# what's the meaning of this? (whitewash, pants dirty, pop them off, pop them in)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the drama 'Miranda' season 2, episode 1, near 6:58,
I see Miranda's mom as she comes downstairs saying (in the subtitles)
'Darling I'm doing a white wash, if your pants are dirty, pop them off, I'll pop them in.'   (But to me it sounds like 'I'm putting on a white wash' instead of 'I'm doing a white wash')

People(the audience) laugh here but I don't get the point. What's the exact meaning of this sentence?  (Miranda used to wallow and lived like a tramp for some time. Miranda pledges to her friend that she will be neat from that day on, that she will be a new person. that's when her mother says this coming down the stairs from upper floor. Something to do with Miranda's dirty clothes?)

Comment: A washing of a load of white clothes.  Colored clothes go in a different load.

Comment: Probably the laughter is triggered by the vigorous way she pursues her new resolve toward cleanliness, involving others in it. HotLicks is right about the whites, but "pop them off" means take the clothes off, and "pop them in" means put them in the washing machine.

Comment: @Robusto Ah, I see. that was the meaning of pop them off, pop them in. if you make your reply an answer, I'll pick that as the selected answer.

Comment: @HotLicks I see.. it clears my understanding. thank you.

Comment: @ChanKim: All right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the laughter is triggered by the vigorous way she pursues her new resolve toward cleanliness, involving others in it. HotLicks is right about the whites meaning a laundry load of white clothes, but "pop them off" means take the clothes off, and "pop them in" means put them in the washing machine.

*Pop* is a generic utility word used to describe sudden, simple-but-deliberate movement, used in this sense:

> 4. To put or thrust suddenly or unexpectedly: *"popping a crisp plump shrimp into her mouth" (Kathleen Winsor)*.

Comment: Worth mentioning for Americans that 'pants' to Miranda and her mother means 'underpants'.

Comment: @TimLymingtonsupportsMonica thanks! that was another important point! (I checked 'pants' in the dictionary and in the U.K. it means panty of U.S.)